# Where is the django admin media folder situated?

Tags: python, django

My admin css is not working.

I tried to find it in folder: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin`

There is no media folder there.

I am using Django 1.5a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have `STATIC_ROOT` defined in your settings.
2. Define `STATIC_URL`.
3. Use `python manage.py collectstatic` command to collect every static file from every app (including `contrib.admin`) in your `STATIC_ROOT` folder.