# Media folder changes in production

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm developing a Django website and I have a media folder where users can upload some stuff. This folder is in my root folder and when I run the server in local (with the ./manage.py runserver) it works fine and put the files in MyApp/media/

The problem is that I have a production server Apache with the website running via mod_wsgi. The folder of my project is in /var/www/MyApp/ and it is creating my media folder in /var/www/media instead of /var/www/MyApp/media.

In my settings I have

```
 STATIC_URL = 'static/'
 MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

And the way I'm creating the path for my uploaded files is this:

```
 def generate_path(self, filename):
     url = "media/files/users/%s/%s" % (self.user.username, filename)
     return url
```

Any idea of what in production it is changing the directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose tu put /var/www/MyApp/media? and change it while I'm in local?

Comment: How do you use generated path?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665968/where-is-the-django-admin-media-folder-situated), 2nd hit searching for "media folder django"

Answer (score 0):

Configure your [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root):

```
# Project root is intended to be used when building paths,
# e.g. ``os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'relative/path')``.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

# Absolute path to the directory that will hold uploaded files.
#
# For more information on ``MEDIA_ROOT``, visit
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'uploads/')
```

Then, use [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to specify path relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: Ensuring you use an absolute path rather than a relative path. IOW, constructing the path relative to the project root is important as shown. This is because the current working directory under Apache will not be your project directory.